# Rails new gives "Could not find proper version of railties (4.2.5.1) in any of the sources" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rvm, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to use Rails 5.0.0.rc1 with Ruby 2.3.1.  However, if I try to create a new project within my "programming" directory, I get this:

```
 ➜  ~/Documents/Programming  rails new foo
Could not find proper version of railties (4.2.5.1) in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

If I do a gem list, the only rails version I have installed in 5.0.0.rc1.  What is interesting is I get the same error when I do rails -v, but do not when I do it from my home directory:

```
 ➜  ~  rails -v
Rails 5.0.0.rc1
 ➜  ~  cd Documents/Programming
 ➜  ~/Documents/Programming  rails -v
Could not find proper version of railties (4.2.5.1) in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling both rails and railties with the same result.  I am using rvm and had to do

```
gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries
```

to install nokogiri.

Comment: Try removing the Gemfile.lock and then running bundle install again.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Run **gem update rails** first, then **bundle update**

Comment: That's what it is!  I figured it out from a combination of your answer and Ed de Almeida's comment. There was a Gemfile and Gemfile.lock in my programming directory when I dont think there should be.  I removed those and now Im good.

Comment: Removing the `Gemfile.lock` is effectively the same as running `bundle update`. `bundle install` uses the `Gemfile.lock` while `bundle update` does not. If there is no `Gemfile.lock` then the two commands are effectively identical.

Comment: I'm not clear why this isn't in the documentation for rvm.

Answer (score -1):

THanks
I didn't need to delete anything
It works just using `bundle update` at directory of my project

try it

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33512577)