# Rails: Bundle install not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, installation

I've generated the app with "rails new" and switched to that directory but when I try to use "bundle install" I get

**An error occurred while installing debug_inspector (0.0.2), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install debug_inspector -v '0.0.2'` succeeds before
bundling.**

any suggestions?

Comment: check This link    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37117230/rails-new-gives-could-not-find-proper-version-of-railties-4-2-5-1-in-any-of-t/37117328#37117328

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem with my rails application. I'm running with JRuby on my Windows machine and this is a common problem for Windows. I had to find the gem which included that gem as a dependency and remove it from my gem file.

In my case, there was a gem causing this name : `gem 'web-console', '2.0.0.beta3'` (probably an old version of the gem since it's a 1 year old project).

You probably need to comment some gem and try to bundle until it works. 
If the gem is essential to the project, you will have to find a way to compile the gem for windows.

It may exist a way to check a tree of dependency to speed up the process.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common error in older versions of ruby. Updating ruby version to 2.1.0 or later will fix this issue.

Comment: my ruby is version 2.3.0